# Enabling microphone with jquery/javascript/php without user having to click allow microphone everytime

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a voice command operated website. Everything works fine but the problem is, user needs to click allow microphone every time on load or after some time if not used.

**Reason:** My website is http not https, so it does not get remembered.

So, **Can microphone be enabled with jquery/javascript/php once the user gives permission?**

I have been searching over the internet for couple of days, yet I could not find any solutions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should make it on HTTPS.

Chrome do right thing this time, it is security.

For http not https website, hackers can hack DNS and start listening from the PC if the user did remember. Note, your server and the client PC are not hacked in this case.

In the case of https, they have to hack either your site to get your certificate.